# Edit SharePoint List Column settings to add color style?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, column-formatting

I am trying to create a Choice column in my SharePoint list. Using Graph API, this works great:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/list-post-columns?view=graph-rest-1.0

However, it creates the choices with no color. I would like to create these choices as labels with colors, as shown in the screenshot below, but I can't find any way to do it either at the creation or when editing the column, in both Graph APIs or SharePoint CSOM.

[image]

Is this even doable programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to apply JSON formatting to SharePoint list column programmatically.

You need to set the `CustomFormatter` attribute to specify your custom JSON formatting for the column.

For Example:

```
var jsonSchema = "<your-json>";

string fieldSchema = "<Field Type='Text' Name='ProjectName' StaticName='ProjectName' 
DisplayName='Project Name' CustomFormatter=" + jsonSchema + "/>";

var simpleTextField = list.Fields.AddFieldAsXml(fieldSchema, true, AddFieldOptions.AddToDefaultContentType);
context.ExecuteQuery();
```

OR if you want to update it using PnP PowerShell, you can use:

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url 'https://<tenant>.sharepoint.com/sites/<siteName>'

Set-PnPField -Identity "ProjectName" -List "List Name" -Values @{CustomFormatter = @'
 <your json>
'@
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ganesh. I was more asking about the choice Pills rather than the conditional formatting. You can see that with choice Pills, I'd have my choices labeled with colors, and that is what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Choice pills are created using JSON formatting only. So, if you have to create the choice pills with different colors for different choice options, first you have to generate the JSON & then use same JSON to update the `CustomFormatter` attribute as mentioned above. You can refer to this [sample JSON](https://github.com/pnp/List-Formatting/blob/master/column-samples/generic-issuestatus-pill/generic-issuestatus-pill.json) to generate your own JSON for choice pills.